# MYSQL: select a date from a table when a condition A satisfies; if date is null, then select date from condition B

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to select `DATE_VALUE` from a table ISO_DATE
When `DATE_QUAL_CD=EFFD`. If above date is null or no record with `DATE_QUAL_CD=EFFD`, then return DATE_VALUE where `DATE_QUAL_CD=PRIM.`
I've tried below:

```
SELECT ISOD.DATE_VALUE
FROM ISO_DATE ISOD
WHERE
(
 (ISOD.DATE_QUAL_CD ='EFFD' AND ISOD.DATE_VALUE IS NOT NULL)
 OR
 (ISOD.DATE_QUAL_CD ='PRIM'
 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ISO_DATE INNERISOD
              WHERE INNERISOD.DATE_QUAL_CD ='EFFD'
              AND INNERISOD.DATE_VALUE IS NULL
              AND ISOD.DATE_ID = INNERISOD.DATE_ID
              )
  )
 )
```

Comment: You've tagged the question with Oracle, but your question heading says MYSQL, which one are you using? What's the issue with the query by the way? Are you getting any errors? Moreover, where's the sample data and expected output which you're supposed to post with the query?

Comment: Sounds like you should be doing a join and a coalesce function to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about *ranking* rows by `DATE_QUAL_CD`?

In this example, `EFFD` exists so its `DATE_VALUE` (100) is returned:

```
SQL> with iso_date (date_value, date_qual_cd) as
  2    (select 100, 'EFFD' from dual union all
  3     select 200, 'PRIM' from dual union all
  4     select 300, 'XXXX' from dual
  5    ),
  6  temp as
  7    (select date_value,
  8         date_qual_cd,
  9         rank() over (order by case when date_qual_cd = 'EFFD' then 1
 10                                    when date_qual_cd = 'PRIM' then 2
 11                                    else 3
 12                               end) rn
 13     from iso_date
 14    )
 15  select date_value
 16  from temp
 17  where rn = 1;

DATE_VALUE
----------
       100

SQL>
```

In this example, `EFFD` doesn't exist so `PRIM`'s `DATE_VALUE` (200) is returned:

```
SQL> with iso_date (date_value, date_qual_cd) as
  2    (select 100, 'ABCD' from dual union all
  3     select 200, 'PRIM' from dual union all
  4     select 300, 'XXXX' from dual
  5    ),
  6  temp as
  7    (select date_value,
  8         date_qual_cd,
  9         rank() over (order by case when date_qual_cd = 'EFFD' then 1
 10                                    when date_qual_cd = 'PRIM' then 2
 11                                    else 3
 12                               end) rn
 13     from iso_date
 14    )
 15  select date_value
 16  from temp
 17  where rn = 1;

DATE_VALUE
----------
       200

SQL>
```

If none of `EFFD` or `PRIM` exist, the above query will return *all rows*. You didn't say what to do in that case, so - for now - that's what you get.